# StyleCop SDK: How to get names of parameters of method containing an element?

Tags: stylecop

I wish to write a custom rule for StyleCop that is the opposite of SA1101; namely, I want a violation to occur if there is a redundant `this.` (similar to ReSharper). This happens if the methods/indexers/delegates/constructors containing the element does not have a parameter that is the same name as the element.

For the custom source analyzer, within the `VisitElement(CsElement element, CsElement parentElement, T context)`, how do I get the names of the parameter of each methods/indexers/delegates/constructors containing the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `CsElement` to `StyleCop.CSharp.IParameterContainer`, then use its `Parameters` property to retrieve the parameters.